# spring boot + jboss = page 403

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jboss, http-status-code-404

I was trying to connect spring boot with jboss for a week... I read many topics on this forum and many of them are too old. I get error 404 every time when i want run server. Can you please help me to config my app with jboss properly?

**UPDATE:**

Thank you for help with error 404. I changed package to "war". But now when I run wildfly server Im getting error 403 (forbidden). I was looking how to fix it and still stay in the same place. It is so hard to get wildfly work with spring boot...

I updated files:
https://github.com/kuzyn007/LibraryCRUD

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>pl.seweryn</groupId>
    <artifactId>LibraryCRUD</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <!-- Spring: boot starter parent -->
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Starter for building web, including RESTful, applications using Spring 
            MVC. Uses Tomcat as the default embedded container -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Starter for using Spring Data JPA with Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Starter for testing Spring Boot applications with libraries including 
            JUnit, Hamcrest and Mockito -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- The spring-boot-devtools module can be included in any project to 
            provide additional development-time features. -->
        <!-- Applications that use spring-boot-devtools will automatically restart 
            whenever files on the classpath change. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSP Standard Tag Library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jsp-api_2.2_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- … -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- … -->

    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <finalName>LibraryCRUD</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**application.properties**

```
# MVC
spring.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.view.suffix=.jsp

# JNDI
spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:jboss/datasources/library

# JPA/HIBERNATE
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=pl.seweryn
spring.jpa.database=H2
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

**Application.java**

```
package pl.seweryn.init;


import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

//@Configuration
//@EnableAutoConfiguration
//@ComponentScan
@SpringBootApplication // same as @Configuration @EnableAutoConfiguration @ComponentScan - alternative

public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: The project you have linked to generates a JAR file (default packaging for Spring Boot apps). You need a WAR file to deployment to JBoss (or any other servlet container). Change the packaging type in the POM file, re-package the project (`mvn clean package`) and then deploy the generated WAR file on JBoss.

Comment: Thank you for answer. After this now i have error 403. Page still dosent load index.jsp :( I updated github repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this instructions: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file

You basically have to package your app as a WAR and implement `SpringBootServletInitializer`.

Comment: Thank you for answer. After this now i have error 403. Page still dosent load index.jsp :(
I updated github repo.

Answer (score 1):

I found many mistakes in my project and now its working. I will write here answer for my app.

1. Physical naming was wrong. It should be: spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl. Or I could delete this line and it will be provided default from spring boot
2. I have Application.class in pl.seweryn.init package. I added @ComponentScan(pl.seweryn)
3. BookDaoImpl was not a spring component. Added line @Component